# How do I find mod of large C(n , r)

Tags: algorithm, math, combinations, modulo

How do I find C (n , r) mod k
where

```
0 < n,r < 10^5
k = 10^9 + 7 (large prime number)
```

I have found links to solve this using [Lucas theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27_theorem) [here](https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/3869/best-known-algos-for-calculating-ncr-m).

But this wouldn't help me in cases where my n , r, K all are large. The extension of this problem is :-

Finding sum of series like :-

```
(C(n,r) + C(n, r-2) + C(n, r-4) + ...... ) % k
```

Original constraints hold.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know algorithm with complexity O(r*log_n)
Firstly look at algorithm to calc C(n,r) without mod k:

```
int res = 1;
for(int i=1; i<=r; i++){
  res*=(n+1-i);
  res/=i;
}
```

In your case, you can't divide, because you use modular arithmetics. But you can multiply on the modular multiplicative inverse element, information about it you can find here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse. 
You code will be like this:

```
int res = 1;
for(int i=1; i<=r; i++){
  res*=(n+1-i);
  res%=k;
  res*=inverse(i,k);
  res%=k;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical use case for dynamic programming. Pascal's triangle gives us

```
C(n, r) = C(n-1, r) + C(n-1, r-1)
```

Also we know

```
C(n, n) = 1
C(n, 0) = 1
C(n, 1) = n
```

You can apply modulus to each of the sub-results to avoid overflow.
Time and memory complexity are both O(n^2)

Comment: `Time and memory complexity are both O(n)`. No! It's `O(n^2)` and this is too much.

Comment: Thanks for catching the mistake. Made the edit.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the faster way will be using modular inverse.

Complexity will be as low as `log(n)`

for example

`ncr( x, y) % m` will be

```
a = fac(x) % m;
b = fac(y) % m;
c = fac(x-y) % m;
```

now if you need to calculate `(a / b ) % m` 
you can do `(a % m) * ( pow( b , m - 2) % m ) // Using Fermat’s Little Theorem`

[https://comeoncodeon.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/modular-multiplicative-inverse/](http://Modular%20Multiplicative%20Inverse)

Comment: Can you explain it in detail ?

Answer (score 0):

`C(n,r) = n!/(r!(n-r)!) = (n-r+1)!/r!`

As `k` is a prime, for every `r < k` we can find its **modular multiplicative inverse** `r^-1` using Extended Euclidean algorithm in `O(lg n)`.

So you may calculate `((n-r+1)!/r) % k` as `(((n-r+1)! % k) * r^-1) % k`.
Do it over `1~r` then you will get the result.